# How to place a widget over a panel HoloViews dynamic map

Tags: matplotlib, bokeh, panel, holoviews

I am trying to display the widgets of a HoloViews dynamic plot (Select, Slider, etc.) over the plot. All I can find is the `widget_location` argument which takes the location relative to the plot (‘left’ , ‘right’, …). But I want it to be placed over the plot, not next to it. I was wondering if there is a way for doing this?

P.S. for instance there is `opts(colorbar_opts={'location':(float,float)})` which can be used to place the colorbar where you want. It would be very useful to have a similar option for widgets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I found the solution! I have to use custom CSS. The code below shows how to do it.

```
import holoviews as hv
import panel as pn
pn.extension('ace')
hv.extension("bokeh")


plots = {}
for i in range(5,10):
    data = {
        "x": list(range(0,i)), "y": [i]*i
    }
    plots[i]=hv.Curve(data).opts(width=500)
hvmap = hv.HoloMap(plots)

left_pos = pn.widgets.IntSlider(value=5, step=1, start=-1000, end=5, name="x")
top_pos = pn.widgets.IntSlider(value=5, step=1, start=5, end=200, name="y")
style = pn.pane.HTML(height=0, width=0, sizing_mode="fixed", margin=0)
css = pn.widgets.Ace(height=150)

@pn.depends(left_pos=left_pos, top_pos=top_pos, watch=True)
def _update_css(left_pos, top_pos):
    value = f"""
.bk.panel-widget-box {{
    left: {left_pos}px !important;
    top: {top_pos}px !important;
}}
"""
    css.value = value
    style.object = "<style>" + value + "</style>"

pn.Column("""# How to overlay widgets on HoloViews Map?

We will be using css to overlay and Panel to create the this tool""",
    hvmap,
    "## Settings",
    left_pos,
    top_pos,
    css,
    style,
).servable()
```

All credits goes to Marc Skov Madsen. Original answer [here](https://discourse.holoviz.org/t/how-to-place-the-widget-over-a-hv-plot/1820)